# Labels doesn't display what i need from SQL database (Linq to SQL)

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a database which holds data i need and i want to display these data in several different labels. I am choosing a Primary Key that represents rows in datatable from combobox and every selected index change i want to retrieve other related details to that specific Primary Key (MID) into labels.

I tried using below code;

```
private void CBMeasDBMID_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
using (LinqDataClassesDataContext dataContext = new 
LinqDataClassesDataContext())
    {
    var query = from x in dataContext.MeasResults
                where x.MoldID == cBMeasDBMID.SelectedValue.ToString()
                        group x by x.MeasId into grp
                        select grp.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).First();
    var result = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).Take(5);

    daGridLastMeas.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    daGridLastMeas.Columns["MeasId"].DataPropertyName = "MeasId";
    daGridLastMeas.Columns["Date"].DataPropertyName = "Date";               
    daGridLastMeas.Columns["Plane"].DataPropertyName = "Plane";
    daGridLastMeas.Columns["Position"].DataPropertyName = "Postn";

    daGridLastMeas.DataSource = result;

    var manuf = from y in dataContext.Moulds
                where y.MID == cBMeasDBMID.SelectedValue.ToString()
                select y.manuf;

    lblManufac.Text = manuf.ToString();

    var size = from a in dataContext.Moulds
               where a.MID == cBMeasDBMID.SelectedValue.ToString()
               select a.Size;

    lblSize.Text = size.ToString();

    var lastmeas = from c in dataContext.MeasResults
                   where c.MoldID == cBMeasDBMID.SelectedValue.ToString()
                   select c.Date;

    lblLastMeasDate.Text = lastmeas.ToString();

    var wi = from d in dataContext.Moulds
                 where d.MID == cBMeasDBMID.SelectedValue.ToString()
                 select d.AWI;

    lblWi.Text = wi.ToString();
        }
    }
```

My problem is code doesn't retrieve the data, instead when i first click to combobox to choose an ID, all labels show **SELECT** text which is Primary Key selection ComboBox's default text and afterwards there is no change or data retrieve even though i change the selected index.
How can i fix this issue?

Comment: When you say "my code doesn't retrieve data", do you mean that 'var query' and 'var result' are empty, or are you saying the data fills, but is not assigning correctly to the datagrid?

Comment: when i debug code, query values are shown equal to integers (which is not normal and integers seem random around 126).

Comment: can you edit your post with Moulds and MeasResults class and send the results for query and result please

Comment: @HockeyJ `var query` has nothing to do with labels. `var manuf`, `var size` etc. are the ones that don't return correct data. `var query` and `var result` return data to datagridview smoothly and in the way i need.

Comment: @matt yes. when i first click combobox, all labels show **SELECT** text which is the combobox's default text, and doesn't change afterwards even though i change the selected index of combobox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    var manuf = (from y in dataContext.Moulds
            where y.MID == cBMeasDBMID.SelectedValue.ToString()
            select y.manuf).FirstOrDefault();

    lblManufac.Text = manuf.ToString();

    var size = (from a in dataContext.Moulds
           where a.MID == cBMeasDBMID.SelectedValue.ToString()
           select a.Size).FirstOrDefault();

    lblSize.Text = size.ToString();

    var lastmeas = (from c in dataContext.MeasResults
               where c.MoldID == cBMeasDBMID.SelectedValue.ToString()
               select c.Date).FirstOrDefault();

    lblLastMeasDate.Text = lastmeas.ToString();

    var wi = (from d in dataContext.Moulds
             where d.MID == cBMeasDBMID.SelectedValue.ToString()
             select d.AWI).FirstOrDefault();

    lblWi.Text = wi.ToString();
```

Think this will solve your problem

Comment: Thank you Matt. It did. What is the logic behind this?

Comment: my english is really poor, so to be simple, if you don't make an action like ToList, First etc your request isn't executed, then return you had was the query instead of the result of the query